# Puppeteer does not seem to work with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, puppeteer

I wrote a program using puppeteer. Locally on my computer it works well. However, this does not return anything when it is executed in a docker.

these are my programs.

my test.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const validUrl = require('valid-url');


var parseUrl = function(url) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url)
    if (!/^(?:f|ht)tps?\:\/\//.test(url)) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }
    return url;
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var myurl = parseUrl(req.query.url);
    if (validUrl.isWebUri(myurl)) {
            (async () => {
      const browser =  await puppeteer.launch();
      const newContext = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
      try {
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(myurl);
      const html = await page.content();
      res.send(html);
      await browser.close();
       } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      } finally {
        await browser.close();
      }
    })()
    } else {
        res.send('Invalid url: ' + urlToScreenshot);
    }
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('App listening on port ' + port)
})
```

my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "puppeteer": "2.0.0",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9"
  }
}
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM buildkite/puppeteer:latest

ENV  PATH="${PATH}:/node_modules/.bin"

# Copy the app
COPY . /app/
#COPY local.conf /etc/fonts/local.conf
WORKDIR app
RUN npm i

# Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser ./node_modules

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

EXPOSE 8080
#ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "test.js"]
```

my launcher.sh

```
docker stop mytest
docker rm mytest
docker build -t mytest.
docker run --name mytest -p 127.0.0.1:8682:8080 -d mytest
```

when I type this curl command, the program runs in a vacuum.

> curl -v -i http://127.0.0.1:8682/?url=https://www.google.com

[image]

My others containers work well with the local ip address (127.0.0.1)
[image]

whereas if I run the nodejs program without a docker, it works very well.

[image]

how can I fix it worries?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59282785/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and fixed this by following modifications

Add this in your docker

```
RUN apk --no-cache add bash g++ gcc libgcc make python chromium    
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true    
RUN yarn global add nodemon    
RUN npm install
```

And pass the following options in puppeteer. Please note that puppeteer version is 5.3.1

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors :true,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
});
```

Comment: `RUN apk --no-cache add bash g++ gcc libgcc make python chromium
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true  
`

its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Make sure `node` is listening on `0.0.0.0`

A container's `localhost` is different from host's `localhost`. To access the a server running in a container, the server must first listen on `0.0.0.0` which means listen on all interfaces for requests (this will allow the server running in the container to receive requests from outside the container - in this case your host machine). Now, once the server is listening on all interfaces, you need to assign a port on the host machine to listen for requests and forward it to the container's port where the server is listening. For this, we use the `-p` option.

As you can see in the above picture (for `docker ps`), in the ports section, there are a few entries of the form `127.0.0.1:port1 -> port2/tcp`. These container have published ports to allow the incoming connections from outside the container.

Edit:

I tried to reproduce the environment by using your files and after the curl request, I get this error:

```
App listening on port 8080
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[1213/074149.395461:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
#0 0x557e2b76fe29 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x557e2b6d3ee3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x557e2b6e86b3 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#3 0x557e2cec9eee service_manager::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#4 0x557e2b30ef6c content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#5 0x557e2b35b76c service_manager::Main()
#6 0x557e2b30d541 content::ContentMain()
#7 0x557e2b35a9dd headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#8 0x557e2b35a73b headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#9 0x557e2901f218 ChromeMain
#10 0x7fca167042e1 __libc_start_main
#11 0x557e2901f0aa _start

Received signal 6
#0 0x557e2b76fe29 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x557e2b6d3ee3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x557e2b76f9b1 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
#3 0x7fca1c68e0e0 <unknown>
#4 0x7fca16716fff gsignal
#5 0x7fca1671842a abort
#6 0x557e2b76e815 base::debug::BreakDebugger()
#7 0x557e2b6e8af9 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#8 0x557e2cec9eee service_manager::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#9 0x557e2b30ef6c content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#10 0x557e2b35b76c service_manager::Main()
#11 0x557e2b30d541 content::ContentMain()
#12 0x557e2b35a9dd headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#13 0x557e2b35a73b headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#14 0x557e2901f218 ChromeMain
#15 0x7fca167042e1 __libc_start_main
#16 0x557e2901f0aa _start
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffd218069a0 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 00007ffd21807c58 r13: 00007ffd21806c38 r14: 00007ffd21807c60 r15: 00007ffd21806c50
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffd218069a0  bp: 00007ffd21806be0  bx: 0000000000000006
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007fca16716fff  sp: 00007ffd21806a18
  ip: 00007fca16716fff efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:337:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:379:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:157:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My guess would be you're able to talk to the service running inside docker but its some application level issue you need to debug. To prove this, I just changed your `test.js` file with a simple nodejs server and I was able to connect to it keeping everything same. I am not a NodeJS expert but you should try this exercise from your end too to confirm this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My others containers work well with the local ip address

Comment: @pi-2r Are you able to get the correct response if you exec into the container and then issue a curl request?

Comment: @pi-2r What do you mean "your other containers work well with the local ip address"? Explain a bit.

Comment: I just edited my request with screenshots...all my containers are accessible from the local address 127.0.0.0.1